# Using Drupal, how to get access to old, no longer available, feed entries?

Tags: drupal, feed

I'm working on a project where I'm asked to aggregate a number of feeds from various websites into a local/searchable database. The project/site is Drupal based and old feeds entries are key data to the project. My question is:

- Is there a way to access old, no longer available, feed entries using Drupal? If not in Drupal, is there a PHP way to accomplish that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupals feed aggregator module in Drupal is the official way to do this.

In the settings there is a select tag of 'Discard items older than:' This only goes up to 6 weeks, but this can be over-ridden in a custom module by using:

```
function MYMODULE_form_aggregator_admin_settings_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['aggregator_clear']['#options'][157784630]  = "Nearly Never aka 5 years";
```

}

As mentioned [here](http://drupal.org/node/60468)

This will automatically grab your feeds for you and store them in the aggregator_item table

Answer (score 2):

Another option is the mature http://drupal.org/project/feedapi or the newer http://drupal.org/project/feeds both of which are designed for parsing feeds into drupal nodes, users, etc.

Feeds (the next generation of feedapi) has the following useful functions:

> Import or aggregate data as nodes,
>   users, taxonomy terms or simple
>   database records.
>
> ```
> * One-off imports and periodic aggregation of content
> * Import or aggregate RSS/Atom feeds
> * Import or aggregate CSV files
> * Import or aggregate OPML files
> * PubSubHubbub support
> * Create nodes, users, taxonomy terms or simple database records from import
> * Extensible to import any other kind of content
> * Granular mapping of input elements to Drupal content elements
> * Exportable configurations
> * Batched import for large files
> ```

Good Luck!